# Can't load keras model using "tf.keras.models.load_model('model.keras')"

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I tried to load saved model by `Loaded_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('model.keras')`

But occurs following error.

Tensorflow version is Version: 2.16.1

Python version is Python 3.12.2

I ran the same code on Google Colab, where it successfully saved and loaded the model. However, when attempting to load a locally trained model, Colab failed to do so.
I tried both .h5 and .keras file formats for saving the model. While both formats were successfully saved, neither could be loaded.

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[9], line 3
      1 import tensorflow as tf
      2 from keras.models import load_model
----> 3 Loaded_model = tf.keras.models.load_model(
      4     # 'model.keras')
      5     'models\dress_classifier_transferlearn.h5')
.
.
.
AttributeError: Exception encountered when calling Flatten.call().

'list' object has no attribute 'shape'

Arguments received by Flatten.call():
  • args=(['<KerasTensor shape=(None, 7, 7, 512), dtype=float32, sparse=False, name=keras_tensor_178>'],)
  • kwargs=<class 'inspect._empty'>
```

Comment: Hello, seems to be a compatibility issue between the model saved and TensorFlow version, if I am not mistaken there were some changes made to the Flatten layers. Check which version of TF was used with the saved model and match the same version in your environment.